# Set of vertices which "cover" directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to know if there is a name for the following thing:

Let $G$ be a directed graph, and $Y$ a subset of vertices of $G$ such that every vertex of $G$ can be reached by a path starting at a vertex in $Y$.

Is there a standard name in graph theory for a set $Y$ with this property? What if $Y$ is of minimal size?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know that there is a name for such a set in the literature.

If I'm not mistaken, I think this set $Y$ will consist solely of those vertices with in-degree $0$ (since $G$ is directed). Indeed, if they have in-degree $0$ they are not reachable from any other vertex. On the other hand, if some vertex does not have in-degree $0$, it is reachable from another vertex, so it's pointless taking that vertex in $Y$.

Cycles in the graph might cause problems though, so you will need to take a vertex from each cycle too to be safe (see the example below, where the only vertex with in-degree $0$ does not suffice). Cycles poke a hole in the argument I made above, that "you can keep going back till you find a vertex of in-degree $0$".

[image]

If $G$ is undirected, the problem is trivial; $Y$ will consist of only one vertex (or one for each component if $G$ is disconnected).

Comment: You want to consider the **strong components**, and take a vertex from each strong component which is not reachable from outside.